# A question of uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions which converges to $f_1$ on $A$ and $f_2$ on $B,$  where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $R^n$. I'm wondering wheather or not $f_n$ converges to $h$ on $A \cup B$?

$$ h\left(x\right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{f_1}\left( x \right), \quad x \in A\\
{f_2}\left( x \right) , \quad x \in B
\end{array} \right.$$

Could anyone help me to give a solution for the problem! If this is wrong, then can you provide a couter-example? thank you!

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? Or some metric space $X$? Some important parts of the story are missing.

Comment: You must  be assuming that either $A$ and $B$ are disjoint or that $f_1$ and $f_2$ agree on $A \cap B$. Otherwise $h(x)$ is not a well defined function.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi $A$ and $B$ are *any sets*. So this must include the case where they are such that $f_1\mid_{A\cap B} \neq f_2\mid_{A\cap B}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say. I'm pointing out that if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $f_1|_A \neq f_2|_B$, then there is $x \in A \cap B$ such that $h(x)$ is not well defined.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi That is clear. I was pointing out that the OP made it explicit that $h$ is defined *for all* subsets $A$ and $B$. Thus, the function $h$ is not well defined, as you pointed out.

Comment: I see what you mean now you've changed it to $f_i|_{A \cap B}$! :)

Comment: I suppose, you are talking about **uniform** convergence? In this case, the claim is true (assuming that all your functions take values in $\Bbb {R} $ (in fact, any metric space will do)). The proof is very easy and a good exercise in learning the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: sorry! I have just fixed it. There is a proof which I did . But I feel it is uncertain! I think that $A,B$ require to be closed or open toghether?

Comment: In my proof, $A,B$ is not neccessary to be closed or open together! However, I doubt my proof. By using a couter-example of the gluing lemma, I see that if $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions, then $f_1, f_2$ are continuous on $A,B$ respectively. On the other hand, $A,B$ are disjoin, thereby I can doubt that $h$ is not continuous on $A \cup B.$

Comment: I am still trying to find a couter-example for this problem!